# show selected estimates in stargazer

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I did a panel data fixed effect with time dummy variables estimation.

```
fe_t <- plm(Y1 ~ X1+dummiesfe-1, data=pdata1, model= "within")
```

But I only want to show the estimates without time dummy in `stargazer` package in order to make a neat table like this:

[image: picture]

How could I do that?

Comment: check out the `omit` argument in the stargazer function

Comment: @GabrielFGeislerMesevage
but I got this error: % Error: Unknown statistic in 'omit.summary.stat' argument.

Comment: Its tough to diagnose the problem if you don't include the code you wrote that generated the problem. Did you include an argument `omit="dummiesfe"` or another similar regular expression? See the link [here](http://jakeruss.com/cheatsheets/stargazer.html#omit-parts-of-the-default-output) for details.

Comment: Yes, I've added`stargazer(fe_ts, omit = "dummiesfe")` and it showed the error. is it because my `dummiesfe` is defined like this `dummiesfe=model.matrix(~time.f, model=c("within"))` and `time.f` is a factor? that's why it doesn't work?

Comment: possibly, I couldn't say without seeing your data. Whatever the name of the dummy variables are in latex output you want to use that name in your regular expression for omitted variables. So if the fixed-effects display as some variant of "time.f" then you should use `omit="time.f"`.

Comment: why not add the time effects to your `plm` model? `fe_t <- plm(Y1 ~ X1, data=pdata1, model= "within", effect = "twoway", index = c("ID", "Year")`.  `stargazer` should then ignore the time effects.

Answer (score 0):

As comment suggests, use a `twoways` effect as option of the `plm` command. This accounts for unit and time fixed effects and `stargazer` can handle it.

```
data("Produc", package="plm")

fe <- plm(pcap ~ hwy + water + unemp,
          data=Produc, index=c("state", "year"), model = "within", effect = "twoways")

stargazer(fe, type="text")

========================================
                 Dependent variable:    
             ---------------------------
                        pcap            
----------------------------------------
hwy                   1.960***          
                       (0.059)          
                                        
water                 1.970***          
                       (0.049)          
                                        
unemp                  -42.600          
                      (27.300)          
                                        
----------------------------------------
Observations             816            
R2                      0.818           
Adjusted R2             0.802           
F Statistic  1,123.000*** (df = 3; 749) 
========================================
Note:        *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```